# WPF ObservableCollection won't bind to ListBox

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listbox

I have an ObservableCollection as a member of my class. This observable collection is filled from a database when a button is clicked which reveals the next screen, and then I would like all of the items in the observable collection to be displayed in a list box.

Here is my code:

```
//Inside My UiPageData class
public ObservableCollection<string> _SavedMachines = new ObservableCollection<string>();

    public ObservableCollection<string> SavedMachines
    {
        get { return _SavedMachines; }

        set
        {
            _SavedMachines.Add(value.ToString());
            NotifyPropertyChanged("SavedMachines");
        }
    }  

public void EventClick()
    {
        if (Instance.CurrentPage != UiPageEnum.eVechWizardScreen)
        {
            Instance.AdvancedSettings.CurrentWizardScreen = VehicleWizardEnum.eLoadVehicle;

            DataManager vechDM = DataManager.getDataManager();
            vechDM.close();
            vechDM.open("Path to DB");

            DataManagement.Machines[] machs = vechDM.getMachines();
            if (machs.Length > 0)
            {
                _SavedMachines.Clear();
                for (int i = 0; i < machs.Length; i++)
                {
                    _SavedMachines.Add(machs[i].Name);
                    Debug.WriteLine(machs[i].Name);
                }

            }
        }
        Instance.CurrentPage = UiPageEnum.eVechWizardScreen;
    }
```

I can see from the `Debug` output that there are 3 items loaded into my Observable Collection.

Then the XAML looks like this:

```
<TextBlock Text="Current Vehicles"
            Style="{StaticResource HeaderStyle}" />
<ListBox Grid.Row="1"
            Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
            ItemsSource="{Binding UiPageData.SavedMachines}">
    <ListBox.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="ListBox"
                BasedOn="{StaticResource WgListBox}">
            <Setter Property="ListBox.IsEnabled"
                    Value="True" />
        </Style>
    </ListBox.Resources>
</ListBox>
```

I'm getting very confused with this, as nothing shows up in the ListBox. I'm a newcomer to C# and WPF and Windows in general, trying to figure out how to make the changes I need to make to existing code. Any help would be gratefully received.

Comment: Have you set your window's `DataContext` ?

Comment: For one, the setter for `SavedMachines` looks very, very wrong ...

Comment: *I have an ObservableCollection as a member function of my class*... no you don't. An `ObservableCollection` is an object, not a function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For one, do this:

```
private ObservableCollection<string> _SavedMachines = new ObservableCollection<string>();
public ObservableCollection<string> SavedMachines
{
    get { return _SavedMachines; }
}
```

Secondly, you're DataContext is more than likely wrong.  You need to figure out what the `DataContext` is of the control your `ListBox` is in.  My guess is that the `DataContext` is either:

1. Your `DataContext` is not set at all
2. `UiPageData` is your `DataContext` meaning you need to do `ItemsSource="{Binding SavedMachines}"`
3. Your `DataContext` is set to something totally different, and we can't really help you with that

You should use tools like Visual Studio's `Output` window and/or `Snoop` to figure out your binding issues.

Also, an `ObservableCollection<string>` seems a little useless.  I would recommend at some point you do `public ObservableCollection<DataManagement.Machines> SavedMachines` and then specify your `ListBox.ItemTemplate` to use a `DataTemplate` that shows the `DataManagement.Machines` object the way you want it to show.

Comment: My DataContext was wrong, I can see the data I was hoping to see in my List Box now. Thanks.

Comment: @Kells1986 See my edit at the bottom.  If you use `ObservableCollection<DataManagement.Machines> SavedMachines` you will be able to do something like `SavedMachines[0].RunMethod` and can access your objects directly rather than having to try and find objects using an alias.

Comment: Yeah thanks, I'm going to look into that tomorrow. Cheers for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Your SavedMachines implementation looks wrong.

you should be adding to SavedMachines instead of  _SavedMachines

ObservableCollection doesnt need OnPropertyChanged. The implementation of your property should have been simply

```
public ObservableCollection<string> SavedMachines{get;set;}
```

Comment: Why downvotes?? I said the implementation is wrong and the OP is binding SavedMachines in xaml and adding to objects to _SavedMachines(which i think was meant to be a private property)??

Comment: The reason I downvoted was because your pre-edit response sounded like you were suggesting his setter should have said `SavedMachines.Add...` instead of `_SavedMachines.Add...` (Both of which are wrong.) Downvote removed.

Comment: Thanks for clarification. I posted the initial response saying the implementation is wrong and then carried on editing it to post more information and then saw all the downvotes :)

Comment: *I posted the initial response saying the implementation is wrong and then carried on editing it to post more information*... well, now you can see that your desperation to get your answer in quickly has led you to receive multiple downvotes. I'd like to point out that reputation and question acceptance is earned by *good* answers, not *quick* answers. Maybe now, you'll write a complete answer before you post it next time? (Not my down vote, by the way).

Comment: Thanks lesson learned. But definitely not looking for quick points or anything. I only post an answer if i cannot explain in a single like in the comments section. Otherwise most of my responses these days have been posting comments only. But it has been a good experience so far on SO :) learning a great deal this way

Comment: 1. this would throw a null exception when trying to access it because OP isn't initializing in code provided 2. 99% of the time you want your `ObservableCollection` to be read only, 3. This would definitely not solve a binding issue because nothing has changed in the context of what ListBox has changed.

Answer (score -1):

I agree with Krishna. Your ObservableCollection should look like this:

```
protected ObservableCollection<string> _SavedMachines = new ObservableCollection<string>();
public ObservableCollection<string> SavedMachines
{
    get { return _SavedMachines; }
    set
    {
        if (_SavedMachines != value) 
        {
          _SavedMachines = value;
          NotifyPropertyChanged("SavedMachines");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why have you declared `_SavedMachines` as `protected`?

Comment: If you want to catch any property changed events for "SavedMachines", then it is a good idea that the underlying object be protected. If an external object had the ability to modify the _SavedMachines object, you might not catch the changes.

Comment: BTW: Within the "set", by checking the value against the current value of the underlying protected object, you avoid generating a property changed event when the value may have not actually changed.

Comment: *If an external object had the ability to modify the _SavedMachines object, you might not catch the changes.*.. then it should be `private`. (Not my down vote though).

Comment: Why do so many programmers default to private? The protections are the same as protected, except that a private member cannot be modified by any derived class. This seems to me to be an unnecessary and often inconvenient restriction.

Comment: It all depends on whether you plan to allow your class to be extended, or not. Most classes will never be extended, so they declare `private` fields. Only when a class is extended might it be worth declaring `protected` fields and/or properties. Perhaps you should read up on [encapsulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_(object-oriented_programming)) for a better and more detailed explanation.